# Calling a callback function on window confirmation on onbeforeunload event

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, onbeforeunload, confirmation

I am in a situation where I have to get window close confirmation while page is being closed.
//Code

```
window.onbeforeunload=function(){

if(...)
{
   return "Are you sure you want to close this window, some changes are pending?";
// need to call a callback function when a user clicks "Leave this page" button.
}
};
```

This creates a confirmation window and I need to call a callback function when the user clicks on the button "Leave this page". Any ideas?

Comment: You want a function to execute when the user agrees to leave the page? Have you tried the `onunload` event?

Comment: There's no such thing, when the user decides to leave, there's no way for you to hinder that, or know that they left etc. A common way to do this kinda thing is to record user action, and if no action is registered within a certain timeframe, assume the user left.

Answer (score 0):

If the user clicks "Leave this page", the closing of the tab / page will continue and therefore the page will be unloaded. Have you tried binding the function you need to call if the user decides to leave the page to the **window.onunload** event? I do not know the details of your scenario, but I think this may solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I didn´t see that @jbabey already suggested this approach.

Comment: My scenario is  : I have a javascript function to make an ajax call when the user leaves the page. When I make ajax call in window.onunload event, especially in chrome, first the page_load event in code behind is being called and only the ajax call request is made after page_load event. But it is fine in IE. I need to control such behaviour of chrome.